# Fire MouseDown Event in ScrollViewer manually WPF

Tags: wpf, events, scrollviewer, raise

I use a TabControl -> ScrollViewer -> Border with pMouseLeftButtonDown handler.... My goal is to implement a drag to scroll scrollviewer...
i have a custom scrollviewer and i cancel all previewmouseleftbuttondown events (Handler on a border inside the template):

```
 private void pMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {



        if (!block)
        {



            block = true;
            lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs = null;

            return;

        }
        else
        {

            block = true;

        }

        lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs = null;


        mouseDragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        scrollStartOffset.X = HorizontalOffset;
        scrollStartOffset.Y = VerticalOffset;

        e.Handled = true;

        lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs = e;

    }
```

In some special cases i would like to fire "lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs" manually. This seems to work because after the raiseEvent() call the method pMouseLeftButtonDown() is called again and this new event won't be blocked (handled = true). The problem is that the ui element gets no mouse event => no mouse left button down, which means no tab selection...

Where is the problem?

```
                FrameworkElement el = lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs.Source as FrameworkElement;
                lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs.Handled = false;

                Debug.WriteLine(el);

                MouseButtonEventArgs newEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, Environment.TickCount, MouseButton.Left) { RoutedEvent = FrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent };
                el.RaiseEvent(lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will actually work, but you will need to change:

```
FrameworkElement el = lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs.Source as FrameworkElement;
```

to:

```
FrameworkElement el = lastPreviewMouseDownMouseButtonEventArgs.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
```

You will probably also need to raise both the `PreviewMouseButtonDown` and the `MouseButtonDown` events. Again, not sure if doing this will actually work for what you want.

Instead, why don't you just get the TabItem that was clicked, and set `IsSelected = true`?

Comment: Hi, i tried OrginalSource but without success :/ The event is raised but this has no impact and i don't know why... A RoutedEvent tunnels first and then bubbles... I try to implement a generic scrollviewer but yeah its possible to extend the tabcontrol and place the logic there and select the clicked tabitem...

Comment: Routed events only tunnel & bubble if the code raising them does so. Since you're the one raising the event, you need to do both. But there is no guarantee that the control will work on MouseDown. You might also have to raise MouseUp, since a lot of actions don't actually take place without a mouse down/up pair. Simulating mouse input gets tricky, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Yeah i know but what is the solution to implement a drag to scroll scrollviewer? In this case if have to write the same logic for a tabcontrol, a listbox, a treeview...

Comment: Well, you could subclass Scrollviewer, handle the mouse events yourself, and call the Scroll* methods to scroll in the proper direction.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100027/wpf-canvas-swallowing-mousedownevent .... Focusable="False" on the ScrollViewer.