# WPF: Canvas swallowing MouseDownEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scrollviewer, mousedown

Can anybody please explain to me why the`MouseDown`event is not reaching the`ScrollViewer`in this easy example?

```
<Window x:Class="MouseDownTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Background="Green" MouseDown="ScrollViewer_MouseDown" PreviewMouseDown="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown">
            <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="Beige" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" PreviewMouseDown="Canvas_PreviewMouseDown">
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MouseDownTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            scrollViewer.AddHandler(MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ScrollViewer_Test));
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_Test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ScrollViewer_Test");
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canvas_MouseDown");
        }

        private void Canvas_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canvas_PreviewMouseDown");
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ScrollViewer_MouseDown");
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown");
        }
    }
}
```

Output when clicking canvas is

```
ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown
Canvas_PreviewMouseDown
Canvas_MouseDown
```

Why is`ScrollViewer_MouseDown`being omitted? I already looked into [this article](http://warren.chinalle.com/2008/07/19/wpf-events-tunneling-and-bubbling/) but the solution given there does not help (or I did it wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to set `Focusable="False"` on the `ScrollViewer` to allow the mouse events to pass though

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Focusable="False" Background="Green" />
```

**Output:**

```
ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown
Canvas_PreviewMouseDown
Canvas_MouseDown
ScrollViewer_MouseDown
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to work, thanks! It seems a bit odd though to set a property on`ScrollViewer`since the`Canvas`seems to swallow the event...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why, but I think it has to do with the default behavior of the ScrollViewer, I think it swallows the event to focus its content, Maybe, just a guess.LOL