# RoutedEvent (MouseUp) bubbling not working for children (Shapes) of Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, canvas

I'm making a simple paint-like application using WPF. I have a Canvas that has Shapes on it. I want to implement selecting feautre. I click and drag a rectangle area that MUST disappear on Canvas MouseUp event. However if cursor is ON the rectangle (or one of the Shapes) the MouseUp event of Canvas won't fire for some reason.

I read this [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#how_event_processing_works) article that describes how routed events work. MouseUp is routed event with RoutedStrategy equals to Bubble. As I read, this means that the children of Canvas will fire Canvas MouseUp event handler if they haven't handled event themself (e.Handled is not set to `true`).

I read a ton of everything on the Internet and have not found any solution\explanation for my problem. Canvas MouseUp just doesn't fire.

Background is set. IsHitTestVisible is true. I tried `canvas.AddHandler(Shape.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnCanvasMouseUp), true);`.  I tried use PreviewMouseUp instead as well as all handlers for specific MouseButton. There are two workarounds:

- Set IsHistTestVisible of shapes to false. But I need them to have IsHitTestVisible == true.
- Detect MouseButton release in Canvas MouseMove event.

Is there any way to make everything work as it SHOULD (according to MS article about RoutedEvents)?  Why is it not working as expected? Is there any way to programatically bubble event to parent?

Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" >

        </Canvas>
```

Add few event handlers:

```
canvas.MouseUp += OnCanvasMouseUp;
canvas.PreviewMouseUp += OnCanvasMouseUp;
canvas.AddHandler(Shape.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnCanvasMouseUp), true);
canvas.AddHandler(Shape.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnCanvasMouseUp), true);
canvas.AddHandler(Shape.PreviewMouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnCanvasMouseUp), false);
canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnCanvasMouseUp;
```

Shapes are added to Canvas like this:

`Canvas.Children.Add(figure);`

## EDIT

Here is an example. When I release mouse button inside the circle or on it's border Canvas.MouseUp doesn't raise.

## Edit2

After `Canvas.Children.Add(shape)` shape still has Parent equals to null.. And there is no way to set it's parent.

[image]

## Edit 3

MouseDown bubbles up correctly.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. MouseLeftButtonUp is firing also when the cursor is over a newly added Rectangle (for example).

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, you DON'T set `e.Handled = true` on any tunneling events, right OP? Also, check out this link. It's slightly different from your scenario but I noticed you haven't tried this out yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100027/wpf-canvas-swallowing-mousedownevent

Comment: @user2619824 I tried your solution. It didn't work. I DO NOT set e.Handled = true. By the way, Shapes doesnt have any event handlers.

Comment: @Clemens, make StrokeThickness bigger. I'll provide a screenshot.

Comment: I've set Fill. What is the relationship between `MainCanvas` in your XAML and the two `canvas` and `Canvas` in your code behind?

Comment: @Clemens it's the same canvas.